# GDAL Library Header Files Error and Warningsin With Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files, gdal

I am using GDAL in visual studio 2019 community version,and I used the sample code in the their official site which is down below,the program compiles, runs and outputs fine, but I got a list of errors and warnings, I don't know if I should ignore them or make some change on header files, anyone encounter issues like this before? hope someone could give me some advice, thank you. 
sample code:

```
/*gdal_test*/
#include <iostream>  
#include <gdal_priv.h>
#include <cpl_conv.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* pszFile;
    GDALAllRegister();
    pszFile = "E:/190807/mosaic_data/S2_1_170215.tif";
    GDALDataset* poDataset = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(pszFile, GA_ReadOnly);
    GDALRasterBand* poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand(1);
    int xsize = poBand->GetXSize();
    int ysize = poBand->GetYSize();
    cout << xsize << endl;
    cout << ysize << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

error list mainly contains these three main issue:

```
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  gdaltest    C:\MSVC_Library\GDAL\warmerda\bld\include   C:\MSVC_Library\GDAL\warmerda\bld\include\ogr_geometry.h    387     

Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  gdaltest    C:\MSVC_Library\GDAL\warmerda\bld\include   C:\MSVC_Library\GDAL\warmerda\bld\include\ogr_geometry.h    1139        

Warning C26812  The enum type 'CPLErr' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   gdaltest    C:\MSVC_Library\GDAL\warmerda\bld\include   C:\MSVC_Library\GDAL\warmerda\bld\include\cpl_error.h   244
```

should I change the syntax in header files? will change it effect something? Or should I just ignore these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that your program, "compiles, runs and outputs fine," so, the **errors** you are seeing are being reported by the "[Intellisense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)" tool in Visual Studio.

To stop displaying these, go to the "Error List" window and select the "Build Only" option:

[image]

The `C26812` **warning** message can be disabled as described in my [answer to your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675144/10871073).

Comment: It works, but... what does this `intelliSense` do in this whole process?

Comment: @ZhouXF That's a *very* interesting question! Many folks (here on SO and elsewhere) will make bizarre gesticulations at you if you mention Intellisense, and maybe will have you driven out of the parish! But it *attempts* to find and highlight coding errors in 'real time' on all source files for a project. However, it often fails because it can't (properly) understand compiler options, conditionally-included code blocks, and many other more subtle code aspects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I just get into more questions. First, what does 'real time' mean, that it attempts to check coding error all the time when I was using visual studio IDE?    Second, no matter I turn this `intelliSense` on or not, the error still exist, why won't these error affect the program? Because far as I know, an `#include library.h` statement replace all the code in that `library` into my .cpp file, so the `intelliSense` finds out there is error in the library.h file and it was written in my file and then the compiler let it pass?This is really confusing me...@Adrian Mole

Comment: @ZhouXF There will probably be 'blocks' of code in the header files that are surrounded with conditional tests, like `#ifdef (some_symbol)` < lines of code > `#endif` which the *actual* compiler doesn't use (because `some_symbol` is *not* defined). However, IntelliSense may think that it *is* defined, and thus will flag errors in those code lines. It can be ***very*** annoying.

Comment: I probably understand it, really appreciate your help,this solves a big issue in my head.@Adrian Mole