# Many Warnings in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Using OpenCV 4.2.0 in C++ with Visual Studio IDE and MSVC compiler I get tons of compiler warnings, 87 to be exact and I have no idea if that is normal or if I've made a misstep in installing and integrating OpenCV into my project.

It doesn't cause the program to crash as far as I can tell by reading and writing images I'm just worried that as my code base grows so will the problem.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   482 
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '12' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '16' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '24' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '32' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '8' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read.  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   301 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    581 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    610 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2245    
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    575 
Warning C6294   Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   559 
Warning C6294   Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   567 
Warning C6294   Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   575 
Warning C6269   Possibly incorrect order of operations:  dereference ignored.   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\any.h 97  
Warning C6201   Index '2' is out of valid index range '0' to '1' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'this->val'.   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   559 
Warning C6201   Index '3' is out of valid index range '0' to '2' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'this->val'.   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   567 
Warning C6201   Index '4' is out of valid index range '0' to '3' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'this->val'.   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   575 
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'data+step.p[0]*i0'.     OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1181    
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'this->data+this->step.p[0]*i0'.     OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1943    
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm'. See line 2686 for an earlier location where this can occur  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2689    
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm'. See line 2700 for an earlier location where this can occur  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2703    
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   385 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::cuda::FeatureSet' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   605 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::UMatUsageFlags' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    3648    
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::flann_algorithm_t' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\kdtree_index.h    59  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::flann_centers_init_t' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\kmeans_index.h    59  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::lsh::LshTable<unsigned char>::SpeedLevel' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   279 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::flann_datatype_t' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\saving.h  51  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::DetectionBasedTracker::ObjectStatus' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\objdetect\detection_based_tracker.hpp   154 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::detail::WaveCorrectKind' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\stitching.hpp   192 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::detail::DpSeamFinder::CostFunction' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\stitching\detail\seam_finders.hpp   125 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::videostab::MotionModel' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\videostab\motion_core.hpp   102 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::float16_t::w' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvdef.h    741 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray::flags' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    116 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray::obj' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    116 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::MatStep::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1554    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::MatStep::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1560    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   542 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,4,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   542 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<float,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   542 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   668 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,4,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   668 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<float,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   668 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,4,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   858 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<__int64,1>::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    974 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<__int64,1>::ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    974 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<double,1>::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    974 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<double,1>::ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    974 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v15::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::pd' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v15::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::pi' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v15::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::ps' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v15::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::pv' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_max_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_mean_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_median_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_min_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_std_dev' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::n_buckets_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::UntypedMatrix::type' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\matrix.h  97  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::detail::RotationWarperBase<cv::detail::CompressedRectilinearPortraitProjector>::projector_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\stitching\detail\warpers.hpp    169 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::detail::RotationWarperBase<cv::detail::CompressedRectilinearProjector>::projector_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\stitching\detail\warpers.hpp    169 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::detail::RotationWarperBase<cv::detail::PaniniPortraitProjector>::projector_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\stitching\detail\warpers.hpp    169 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::detail::RotationWarperBase<cv::detail::PaniniProjector>::projector_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\stitching\detail\warpers.hpp    169 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   301 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   301 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   482 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   482 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    581 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    581 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    610 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    610 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2245    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2245    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    575 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    575 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   359 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   360 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc.hpp 4908    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc.hpp 4925    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\objdetect.hpp   127 
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\async.hpp  73  
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1419    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1444    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    3937    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    3961    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   OpenCV_Tutorials    C:\Users\nayja\Desktop\OpenCV Projects\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\ptr.inl.hpp    258
```

Comment: Always enable as many warnings as you can. Make them errors, and *fix* them. The compiler is trying to help you - let it. Most of those warnings are probably real bugs.

Comment: @JesperJuhl are you recommending OP to fix the bugs in the OpenCV headers?

Comment: @ThomasSablik That wouldn't be a bad thing to do.. Especially not if those fixes were subsequently upstreamed.

Comment: You can do something like this: `#pragma warning( push )\n#pragma warning( disable : 6385, 6297, 6201, etc. )\n#include "OpenCV headers"\n#pragma warning( pop )` Sorry for horrible formatting

Comment: @ChrisMM Ignoring the errors/warnings doesn't *fix* anything.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, fixing third party libraries is not necessarily a good idea. Is he supposed to scope all the enums? That would probably break so many different things.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's not always good to go messing about with 3rd-party header files.

Comment: @ChrisMM If we don't fix third-party libraries when we find issues with them, how are they ever going to get fixed? Be a good open-source siticen and fix stuff when you notice a problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, the issues should be reported to the library maintainers, or fixed in the library with proper push/pull requests. Not fixed locally only. Also, things like C6385 are often false positives, and can't be fixed.

Comment: As I was typing my answer, I thought it seemed familiar: it's very a very similar issue to that posted a few days ago, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675036/c-syntax-header-file-errors/59675144#59675144 (I blame jet-lag for not spotting the 'dupe' earlier!)

Comment: @Nxte If the suggested 'duplicate' does *not* answer your question, please explain why and I shall *consider* restoring my answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole it did answer my question, thanks all. I think I will raise the issue on the opencv github to try to get a response from the team.